# How to validate if Text entered is a numeric number?

Tags: java, swing, programming-languages, validation, joptionpane

I have a calculation application which I need to validate the fields to check if the values entered are numeric numbers and not alphanumeric. I have some ideas about the codes.
Please guide me if I have done anything wrong or seem noob as this is my first time trying out Swing.

```
private void jTextField1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String text1 = jTextField1.getText();            // TODO add your handling code here:
}

private void jTextField2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String text2 = jTextField2.getText();        // TODO add your handling code here:
}

private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    if (text1 and text2 != <numeric number>){
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Please enter numbers only", "naughty", JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION);
    }
    // First we define float variables.
    float num1, num2, result;
    // We have to parse the text to a type float.
    num1 = Float.parseFloat(jTextField1.getText());
    num2 = Float.parseFloat(jTextField2.getText());
    // Now we can perform the addition.
    result = num1+num2;
    // We will now pass the value of result to jTextField3.
    // At the same time, we are going to
    // change the value of result from a float to a string.
    jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(result));
    // TODO add your handling code here:
}
```

Please do help. By the way why does my NetBeans keep informing me that it does not recognize the "JOptionPane" Command?

Comment: import java.swing.JOptionPane;

Comment: if you need formatted text, use JFormattedTextField

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`Float.parseFloat()` will throw a `NumberFormatException` if the `String` isn't numeric and cannot be parsed into a `Float`. You can add a `try-catch` block to check for this condition:

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    float num1, num2, result;

    try {
        num1 = Float.parseFloat(jTextField1.getText());
        num2 = Float.parseFloat(jTextField2.getText());
        result = num1+num2;
        jTextField3.setText(String.valueOf(result));

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Please enter numbers only", "naughty", JOptionPane.CANCEL_OPTION);
    }
}
```

Comment: samG your method works! Your explination is also very clear! Thanks for the help! But I still can't get the NetBeans to recognize the JOptionPane...

Answer (score 2):

If alphanumeric input is not valid for the Swing component in the first place, then instead of validating this post-entry, you should restrict the component to accept only certain format in the first place.

> Using the formatters that Swing provides, you can set up formatted text fields to type dates and numbers in localized formats. Another kind of formatter enables you to use a character mask to specify the set of characters that can be typed at each position in the field. For example, you can specify a mask for typing phone numbers in a particular format, such as `(XX) X-XX-XX-XX-XX`.

That said, you can, among other things, use [`Integer.parseInt(String s)`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt%28java.lang.String%29) to see if an arbitrary string can be parsed into an `int`; the method throws [`NumberFormatException`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/NumberFormatException.html) if it can't. There are also [`Double.parseDouble`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#parseDouble%28java.lang.String%29), etc.

#### See also

- [Java Tutorials/Swing/How to use Formatted Text Field](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/formattedtextfield.html)

  - [How to use the Focus Subsystem/Input Validation](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification)
- [Java Tutorials/Internationalization/Formatting](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/index.html) - [Numbers and Currencies](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/numberintro.html)

#### Related questions

- [A simple way to create a text field (or such) that only allows the user to enter ints/doubles in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2510047/what-is-a-simple-way-to-create-a-text-field-or-such-that-only-allows-the-user-t)
- [A textbox class only accept integers in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2406271/a-textbox-class-only-accept-integers-in-java)
- [Validating an integer or String without try-catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2485694/validating-an-integer-or-string-without-try-catch) - [`java.util.Scanner`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) option

Answer (score 1):

```
try {
    Integer.parseInt(foo);
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // Naughty
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
String temp = txtField.getText();
try 
  {
    int val = Integer.parseInt(temp);
  }
catch(NumberFormatException e) {
  System.out.println("Invalid");
 }
```

To make it more enjoyable, use JOptionPane (makes it more more interactive)

Answer (score 0):

```
textFieldCrDays = new JTextField();
    textFieldCrDays.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        //// validate onlu numeric value
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            if (textFieldCrDays.getText().length() < 3 && e.getKeyChar() >='0' && e.getKeyChar() <= '9')
            {
                // Optional
                super.keyTyped(e);
            }
            else
            {
                // Discard the event
                e.consume();
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: this code is work properly i tried and then after i posted please use this code

Comment: Why commenting your own answer ?

Answer (score -1):

A relatively old question, but I figured I would take a shot at it, to maybe help out the random Google Searches.

Another approach someone could take to minimise code and reduce the number of additional classes is to add a `KeyListener` for the keyType event and check for the *Char* value. This isn't very portable (you can't use region specific formatting such as numerical punctuation), but this could be quite helpful for straight integers.
You could also do a relative length here as well:

```
textField.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter()
{
    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent)
    {
        if (textField.getText().length() < 3 && keyEvent.getKeyChar() >= '0' && keyEvent.getKeyChar() <= '9')
        {
            // Optional
            super.keyTyped(keyEvent);
        }
        else
        {
            // Discard the event
            keyEvent.consume();
        }
    }
});
```

You can also add another event listener to validate the entire integer for further processing (the entire number must be > 800 and < 5220 for example).
A good place for this would be on the focusLost event(?).

*If you are doing these features frequently, it would be best to subclass the JTextField class to provide this functionality.*

**EDIT: Using `Character.isLetter(keyEvent.getKeyChar())` is even more clear.**

Comment: no, keyListener is not the answer, nor is subclassing JTextField

Comment: @kleopatra An explanation would be nice to help improve our processes?