# Java while loop to draw lines

Tags: java

Hello everyone i am trying to do a exercise from a Java book and what i need to do is draw lines and within a textfield i have to say how far the distance between the lines have to be. All of this has to be in a loop so no hardcoded lines.

i have made everything like i thought it should be done but i get some weird error in my console that is keep coming. the error code is as followed:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: ""
>       at java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:48)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:470)
>       at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
>       at h03.LinePanel.paintComponent(LinePanel.java:30)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.paint(JComponent.java:1037)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent._paintImmediately(JComponent.java:5106)
>       at javax.swing.JComponent.paintImmediately(JComponent.java:4890)
>       at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:812)
>       at javax.swing.RepaintManager.paintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:714)
>       at javax.swing.RepaintManager.prePaintDirtyRegions(RepaintManager.java:694)
>       at javax.swing.RepaintManager.access$700(RepaintManager.java:41)
>       at javax.swing.RepaintManager$ProcessingRunnable.run(RepaintManager.java:1672)
>       at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(InvocationEvent.java:209)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(EventQueue.java:702)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue.java:82)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:663)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue$2.run(EventQueue.java:661)
>       at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
>       at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(AccessControlContext.java:87)
>       at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(EventQueue.java:672)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(EventDispatchThread.java:296)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(EventDispatchThread.java:211)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(EventDispatchThread.java:201)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:196)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(EventDispatchThread.java:188)
>       at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(EventDispatchThread.java:122)

since i am new to Java i don't know what i did wrong and how to troubleshoot this error so i would appreciate any help! the code in my panel that i use for this is

```
DrawLines lines = new DrawLines();

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    super.paintComponent(g);
    int positionY = getHeight() - Integer.parseInt(afstand.getText()); // absolut positioning

    int yPos = 0;

    while(yPos <= positionY) {

        lines.drawLines(g, 0, yPos, getWidth(), yPos);
        yPos = yPos + Integer.parseInt(afstand.getText());
    }

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    try {

        repaint();


    }
    catch(NumberFormatException err) {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "something went wrong! heeft u wel    een waarde opgegeven?");

    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is exactly what it says: you call `Integer.parseInt()` on an empty String, in your example: `afstand.getText()`, and it does not like it.

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "" at
[...]
java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:470) at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:499)
```

To avoid the exception you could catch the exception:

```
try {
    int input = Integer.parseInt(afstand.getText());
    //rest of your code
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    //let the use know that the entry is invalid
}
```

Comment: I'd like to add the suggestion, that you check the input for non-Number chars before trying to parse it to Integer.

Comment: But how come it already checks the textfield when i start debugging? i mean it's not in the constructor so it has to wait till i have put in a value or am i thinking the wrong way?

Comment: @Fildor I've done that - although that check should probably done in the component itself, for example through a Document, rather than in the paintComponent method.

Comment: @Reshad `paintComponent` is called as soon as your component is visible - and it means you have not had time to enter anything yet (unless you populate the field before it is shown).

Comment: @assylias I agree. This is a special case I guess.

Comment: @assylias hmm and where do i have to put this try and catch block? and what do you mean with populate the field?

Comment: @Reshad Quick and dirty: put the try/catch block in your paintComponent method.

Comment: @assylias i see in the console the error shown but after i put in a value it works kinda but this is a very dirty way is there not a better way to do this?

Comment: @Reshad I think you should review your design and parse that information outside the paintComponent method. See for example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3412135/how-to-validate-if-text-entered-is-a-numeric-number Or you can use an InputVerifier: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/focus.html#inputVerification

Comment: But how can i draw the lines in a while loop outside the paintComponent?

Comment: @Reshad Read the input as in the examples I linked to, store the result in a field and access that field from paintComponent.

Comment: i changed it a bit and i get a different error now.. 

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at h03.LinePanel.<init>(LinePanel.java:26)
 at h03.Frame.<init>(Frame.java:16)
 at h03.Main.main(Main.java:10)

the link where u can see my code https://github.com/reshadf/Java/blob/master/DeBasis/src/h03/LinePanel.java

Answer (score 0):

getText().toString() to get the value of your Textfield. You can try System.out.println(afstand.getText) and with toString to see the difference.

Otherwise there is no integer value in your Textfield.